# Grunt recess - how to check less

Tags: gruntjs, less, lint, recess

I want to check a less file for valid code. I used the grunt plugin "[grunt-recess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-recess)" and it works, but not as I want. This ist the part in Gruntfile.js:

```
recess: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            "less/base.less"
        ]
    }
}
```

If I write the following in my less file

```
.test {
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px


}
```

... it complains about the incorrect property order. But why it doesn't complain about the the missing ; and the blank lines?
Maybe it's very easy, but not for me. It's the first time I'm using grunt and I'm not finding a solution (I used google a lot). I also tried "[lesslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-lesslint)", but it didn't work either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, in short: `recess` does not really lints Less code but instead it actually checks the CSS compiled from it. Hence it doesn't complain of missing `;` and blank lines simply because compiled CSS do not have those. (And answering your next question: No, there're no "real" Less linting tools, all existing tools declaring themselves as such actually lint compiled CSS result instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer but unfortunately no solution:

> "Well, in short: recess does not really lints Less code but instead it
>   actually checks the CSS compiled from it. Hence it doesn't complain of
>   missing ; and blank lines simply because compiled CSS do not have
>   those. (And answering your next question: No, there're no "real" Less
>   linting tools, all existing tools declaring themselves as such
>   actually lint compiled CSS result instead)."
>   - seven-phases-max